# hg-git deploy to heroku from Lion

Tags: macos, git, mercurial, heroku, hg-git

I have this application on my Lion machine that is in a mercurial repository so I'm using hg-git to deploy it to heroku.

~/.hgrc

```
[extensions]
hgext.bookmarks =
hggit =
```

.../project/.hg/hgrc

```
[paths]
default = https://validhgrepo.com

[alias]
push-heroku  = push git+ssh://git@heroku.com:appname.git
```

Then when I run hg push-heroku it should deploy, but instead I get:

```
caseys-MacBook-Air:project casey$ hg push-heroku
pushing to git+ssh://git@heroku.com:appname.git/
creating and sending data
["git-receive-pack 'appname.git/'"]

 !  Invalid path.
 !  Syntax is: git@heroku.com:<app>.git where <app> is your app's name.

abort: git remote error: The remote server unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

This doesn't make any sense. I feel like the error message is misleading because that repository DOES exist.

Also this works perfect on my ubuntu machine with a similar setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was related to this [issue](https://github.com/schacon/hg-git/issues/34). I hadn't noticed the extra slash before.  I applied a patch similar to this [guy](https://github.com/schacon/hg-git/issues/226) and it worked for me (on latest hg, hg-git and osx).

Full details of how to install the patch:

1. first uninstall it

   ```
   sudo easy_install -m 'hg-git'
   ```
2. then delete the hg-git egg file in ~/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
3. install as directory

   ```
    sudo easy_install -Z 'hg-git'
   ```
4. open ~/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/hg_git..../hggit/git_handler.py
5. apply patch by hand (mine was more like line 1118)

   ```
   --- git_handler.py  Thu Jul 28 22:05:45 2011
   +++ patched.git_handler.py  Thu Jul 28 22:11:44 2011
   @@ -1066,6 +1066,8 @@

                   port = None
                   host, path = hostpath.split(hostpath_seper, 1)
   +               if (host.find('heroku') > 0):
   +                    path = path.rstrip('/')
                   if hostpath_seper == '/':
                   transportpath = '/' + path
                   else:
   ```

Answer (score -2):

Your git remote format is screwed.

In .git/config ensure that your remote takes the format of:

```
git@heroku.com:appname.git
```

where `appname` is your applications name on Heroku

Comment: I don't have a .git folder as this project is in HG not git.

Comment: True, but you're still using Git when talking to Heroku - you need to work out where that remote is set.

Comment: `hg-git` (which OP is using) explicitly does not use git. So no, OP isn't using git while talking to Heroku.